# how do i fix my purge function in discord.py?

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py, purge

this is my purge command. I am very new to slash commands.

```
@bot.command(name="purge", description="Purge a specific amount of messages.", guild=guild_ID)
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx: discord.Interaction, num_messages: int):

    if num_messages < 1:
        await ctx.response.send_message("You must provide a valid number of messages to delete.", ephemeral=True)
        return

    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num_messages)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=f"✅ Deleted {len(deleted)} messages.")
    await ctx.response.send_message("", ephemeral=True, embed=embed)
```

this is the error i am geting
"404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction"

I have now tried searching everywhere on github/stackoverflow to find a solution on my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator [@bot.command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command) creates a text command (those that are triggered by messages using the bot prefix).
If you want to create an application command, also known as Slash Command, you should use decorator [@app_commands.app_command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.CommandTree.command) or [@bot.hybrid_command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.hybrid_command) to create a command hybrid (will work for both text and interaction using `/`).

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(name="purge")
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx: commands.Context, num_messages: commands.Range[int, 1]):
    """Purge a specific amount of messages

    Args:
       num_messages: the amount of messages to delete
    """
    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num_messages)
    embed = discord.Embed(description=f"✅ Deleted {len(deleted)} messages.")
    await ctx.reply(ephemeral=True, embed=embed)
```

> - Note that I used [commands.Range](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Range) to ensure that `num_messages` will be a larger integer that 1. So you don't need to check this value;
> - I'm using [docstrings](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.describe) to describe the function of the command and arguments. These descriptions will automatically be used by the application commands;
> - You will need to [sync your commands](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f) with discord whenever you create a new one or change their syntax (parameters, name, descriptions).